# How do you present any data type to the user with PureScript?

Tags: purescript

I want to make a very human-friendly development environment, and I'm considering using PureScript to provide the language part. I see that out of the box, `Show` doesn't work on records of things which are instances of `Show`:

```
log (show {a:5})
```

The 'Try PureScript!' (http://try.purescript.org/) compiler says:

```
   No type class instance was found for

   Prelude.Show { a :: Int
                }
```

Is there a tool for generically printing any data structure, especially one containing records? Is there some type trickery that would support generically walking over the record to support my own class like `present :: Present a => a -> Presentation`? The problem is that I don't know what the types will be ahead of time. The user enters a record and I want to be able to present it. It seems that I'll have to patch the compiler to support this.

Answer (score 2):

Records are disallowed in instance heads. For discussion and reasons, see [this thread](https://github.com/purescript/purescript/issues/1822).They must be wrapped in `data` or `newtype` if we want to write instances for them.

However, there is a [generics library](https://github.com/purescript/purescript-generics) and a deriving mechanism that lets us generate `Show` instances.

```
import Data.Generic

data Foo = Foo {a :: Int} | Bar {b :: String}
derive instance genericFoo :: Generic Foo

instance showFoo :: Show Foo where
   show = gShow
```

Comment: This is okay if I know the types ahead of time, but suppose I just want to work with arbitrary records that the user might type in without having to wrap them up in a name. (Indeed, half of the point of using PureScript for me is that it has ad-hoc records without the need to declare them like in Haskell.) Is there no recourse?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  Your wish has been expressed in the linked discussion but there are also points against. You could take a look at [`purescript-debug`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-debug/0.1.7/docs/Debug.Trace) because IIRC it can do some JS-based native printing, and records are mapped straightforwardly to JS objects.

Answer (score 1):

Working with untyped data in PureScript is done using the `purescript-foreign` or the `purescript-argonaut` libraries. I'd suggest argonaut.

The representation of a record with unknown fields and unknown types for these fields would be: `StrMap Json` from the `purescript-maps` package. I'd suggest you take a look at the (not yet merged) documentation over here: https://github.com/hdgarrood/purescript-argonaut-core/blob/565c7e650c51c45570663cf1838ec9cfa307a9c7/README.md. I've also put together a little example, showing how to match on a heterogeneous array from JavaScript:

```
-- src/Main.purs
module Main where

import Prelude
import Control.Monad.Eff (Eff)
import Control.Monad.Eff.Console (CONSOLE, log)
import Data.Argonaut (foldJson, Json)
import Data.Foldable (traverse_)

newtype Presentation = Presentation String

unPresentation :: Presentation -> String
unPresentation (Presentation p) = p

instance showPresentation :: Show Presentation where
  show = unPresentation

class Present a where
  present :: a -> Presentation

instance presentInt :: Present Int where
  present = Presentation <<< show

instance presentNumber :: Present Number where
  present = Presentation <<< show

instance presentBoolean :: Present Boolean where
  present = Presentation <<< show

instance presentString :: Present String where
  present = Presentation

presentJson :: Json -> Presentation
presentJson =
  foldJson
    (const (Presentation "null"))
    present
    present
    present
    (const (Presentation "array"))
    (const (Presentation "record"))

foreign import vals :: Array Json

main :: forall e. Eff ( console :: CONSOLE | e) Unit
main = traverse_ (log <<< show <<< presentJson) vals
```

And the corresponding js file:

```
// src/Main.js
// module Main

exports.vals = [1, 1.2, "hello", true, [1,2,3], {a: 3, b: "hi"}];
```

Running this program gives you:

```
> pulp run
* Building project in/home/creek/Documents/so-christopher-done
* Build successful.
1.0
1.2
hello
true
array
record
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [traceAny](https://github.com/garyb/purescript-debug/blob/e2e2bbe01ed61b2862ec4c0bd55a979ab7c4990f/src/Debug/Trace.purs#L24) and related functions from `purescript-debug`. Here are a few examples: [test/Main.purs#L22](https://github.com/garyb/purescript-debug/blob/e2e2bbe01ed61b2862ec4c0bd55a979ab7c4990f/test/Main.purs#L22). I'd post the links to Pursuit, but it doesn't seem to have `purescript-debug` at the moment.